# Is it possible to run fortran file in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, fortran

I installed fortran kernel in jupyter notebook and It is possible to write and run fortran codes in Jupyter. I have some fortran files with `*.FOR` extension, Is it possible to run this files from jupyter notebook?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see whether it works or not.  It is faster than waiting for an answer

Comment: If you are using the OpenCoarrays Fortran Jupyter binder provided by the SourceryInstitute You can pass compiler flags via the Jupyter Magic `%fcflags`, like `%fcflags: -ffixed-form` to parse the files as fixed-form source code. But why would you even want to specify this flag, when the compiler can automatically recognize the file format for you? https://hub.gke.mybinder.org/user/sourceryinstitu-yter-caf-kernel-rabg9utm/notebooks/index.ipynb

Comment: Hi @cup, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Hi @King, Thank you for your answer, I want to use widget's Jupyter Notebook to create GUI for input data then send input data to run with fortran main code. This is my idea, but I don't know is it possible or not. Unfortunately, your URL address: "Oops! We can't seem to find the Binder page you are looking for."